# CSS Styling didn't get applied when class added dynamically for the element through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Now, this looks like pretty simple, but I don't know why it is not working.
I have a HTML file name g.html which inclues jquery, jquery ui, jquery touch punch nicely.
and also includes g.js
now, inside g.js  use jquery to dynamically modify the class of an element.
A new class is added for the element.
as is evident from the output HTML code:

```
<td class=" ui-datepicker-days-cell-over currentDay ui-datepicker-current-day ui-datepicker-today" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="11" data-year="2013"><a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-state-active" href="#">26</a></td>
```

"currentDay" is the class I wanted and it is now added.
Anyhow, I have a css for currentDay in g.html which says:

```
.currentDay {
    background-image:url('tick.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#ad5;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

but this styling doesn't gets applied at all?
What's wrong? What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried putting the class on the `<a>` tag instead of the `<td>`?

Comment: @JamesMohler I am making use of http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay I do not think that is possible.

Comment: @coder Yes it is, just change `.currentDay` to `.ui-state-default` see [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `!important` keyword at your `.currentDay` class.
The `!important` rule makes your styles always to be applied if there are also any other styles too on same element .in your case there are many classes applied with `currentDay` class to same element. To give first priority to 
styles at currentDay class use `!important` keyword with styles that you defined at your class

```
  .currentDay {
        background-image:url('tick.jpg') !important;
        background-repeat:repeat-x !important;
        font-weight: bold !important;
        color:#ad5 !important;
        border: 1px solid #aaa !important;
    }
```

Comment: @SemirTurgay If you want my upvote, explain why it works, because it would *also* work if you just told the OP to remove other code that changes the style to `.currentDay`, I think this is bad practice.

Comment: The !important rule is make your styles always to be applied if there are any other styles too . in this case there are many classes applied with currentDay class